# Which class parses the Hive & Ping into Map Reduce

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

Which is the class that parses the pig & hive commands into Map Reduce jobs, 
and what is the algo behind this parsing ?

Answer (score 4):

Pig and Hive are both use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to build a compiler to parse their scripts. If you are not familar with the compiler theory, I suggest you read some related material.

For Pig, the source codes for ANLTR are `src/org/apache/pig/parser/QueryLexer.g` and `src/org/apache/pig/parser/QueryParser.g`. They will be compiled to `org.apache.pig.parser.QueryLexer` and `org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser`. However, these two classes are used to compile your Pig script to an abstract syntax tree. Then it will be transformed to `org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LogicalPlan`. After that, LogcialPlan will be transformed to `org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.plans.PhysicalPlan`. Here I listed some related source files:

```
org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LogicalPlan
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.plans.PhysicalPlan
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.plans.MROperPlan
org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(String)
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.compile(LogicalPlan, Properties)
org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PhysicalPlan, String)
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.compile(PhysicalPlan, PigContext)
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(MROperPlan, MapReduceOper, Configuration, PigContext)
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(MROperPlan, String)
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(PhysicalPlan, String, PigContext)
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POLocalRearrange.constructLROutput(List<Result>, List<Result>, Tuple)
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce.Map.collect(Context, Tuple)
```

For Hive, the source code for ANLTR is `ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/parse/Hive.g`. It will be compiled to `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveLexer` and `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser`. These two classes are used to compile your Hive script to an abstract syntax tree. Then it will be transformed to `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.QueryPlan`. The mapper and reducer in Hive are ExecMapper and ExecReducer.

Here I listed some related source files:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(String)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(String, Context)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(String, Context)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ASTNode
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.QueryPlan
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(String, boolean)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute()
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator
```

At last, I suggest you download their source codes and browse them in the eclipse to find out any question you want to know by yourself.